# Does BitConverter.GetBytes() always allocate a new byte[] every time?

Tags: c#

`BitConverter.GetBytes(SomeType)` always return a `byte[]`, it seems like a new `byte[]` is created in memory every time I call it, and be recovered by GC some time later. I need to call it many times to convert a lot of data to bytes, will it be an impact to performance?
Is there another method like `GetBytes(SomeType input, byte[] buffer)` that write the data to your own buffer?
The use case is that I am going to serialize some data into a file in binary format.

Comment: You are going to have *different* arrays for different types (`byte[8]` for `long`, `byte[2]` for `char`). If `SomeType` is fixed you can get the corresponding implementation https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,6cbc9ca56474540e

Comment: A modern application, if it's primarily working with primitve types, can use [System.Buffers.Binary.BinaryPrimitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=netcore-3.1). You'll be working with `Span`s rather than `byte[]`s directly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the implementations of `BitConverter.GetBytes` look like this:

```
public static byte[] GetBytes(ulong value)
{
    return GetBytes((long)value);
}
```

Or

```
public unsafe static byte[] GetBytes(long value)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[8];
    byte[] array2 = array;
    fixed (byte* ptr = array2)
    {
        *(long*)ptr = value;
    }
    return array;
}
```

All of them ultimately allocate a new array.

The code above was decompiled using ILSpy.

Comment: You are creating a new array in memory here too  `byte[] array = new byte[8];`

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras - No, I'm not. This is code from the framework itself. It's decompiled code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `BitConverter` itself is not that smart so far.

Yet it depends on what kind of data are you going to convert? I assume primitive types like `int` or `string`. Then you can do much better with caching: for example, `Dictionary<int, byte[]>` would give you great performance improvement: essentially, you will convert each distinct integer to bit array exactly once, then store it in the dictionary; all the other attempts to convert **the same** integer to a byte array will retrieve cahced instance.

Actually, the same approach will work for non-primitives as well, but you have to maintain right implementatin of both `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.